# Stochastic convergence (product)

Tags: measure-theory, convergence-divergence

Consider the measurable space $(\Omega,\mathcal{A},\mu)$. Let $f,f_1,f_2,\ldots$ be measurable functions and $A,A_1,A_2,\ldots\in\mathcal{A}$. Let $(f_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ be convergent stochastically to $f$ and $(1_{A_n})_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ be convergent stochastically to $1_A$.

My question is if then $(f_n1_{A_n})$ converges stochastically to $f1_A$.

If yes how can I see that using the following definition:

In our reading, we defined stochastic convergence as follows:

> > Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{A},\mu)$ be a measurable space.
> >     A series $(f_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ converges locally stochastic to the measurable function $f$, if for all $A\in\mathcal{A}$ with $\mu(A)<\infty$ and for all $\varepsilon>0$ it is
> >     $$
> > \lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\mu(A\cap\left\{\omega\in\Omega: \lvert f_n(\omega)-f(\omega)\rvert >\varepsilon\right\})=0.
> > $$
> >     Is this for $A=\Omega$, too, we call it stochastic convergence.

Comment: It is more commonly called convergence in measure

Comment: Give me a shout in the chat if you are convinced.

Comment: Dude see answer change. I made a pretty stupid error yesterday.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: triangles inequality

Consider something like $f1_{A}-f1_{A_n}+f1_{A_n}-f_n1_{A_n}$

Edit. So i was wrong the correct argument is this, thanks to a similar question asked about someone else

$\{\omega \in\Omega : f|1_A-1_{An}|>\epsilon \}\subset \{\omega\in\Omega:|1_A-1_{An}|=1\}$ which we know has measure going to 0.

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand what you mean. Maybe you can explain it a little bit more detailed?

Comment: You write down the definition of stochastic convergence for $f_n1_{A_n}$ converging to $f1_A$ and try to use the hints i gave you. I am on an ipad so i am not writing any more latex

Comment: I then get that $\left\{\lvert f_n1_{A_n}-f1_A\rvert>\varepsilon\right\}\subset\left\{\lvert 1_A(f-f_n)\rvert>\varepsilon/2\right\}\cup\left\{\lvert f_n(1_A-1_{A_n}\rvert>\varepsilon/2\right\}$. Does this help?

Comment: @mathfemi Yes, keep going... What do you know about measure of union of two sets? Why can you make them arbitrarily small?

Comment: In order to continue it is $\left\{\lvert 1_A (f-f_n)\rvert>\varepsilon/2\right\}\subset\left\{\lvert f-f_n\rvert>\varepsilon/2\right\}$. But I do not see how I can estimate the other set.

Comment: @mathfemi you know the latter has measure converging to 0 because $f_n$ converges to $f$ in measure. I assume you solved it yourself by now?

Comment: But what is with the set $\left\{\lvert f_n(1_A-1_{A_n})\rvert > \varepsilon/2\right\}$?

Comment: I made a mistake. See changed answer. I now think it works

Comment: Its the same as before only the summands are changed.

Comment: It is now easier because before you have fn so that the function changes every value of n, now you actually fixed the function

Comment: The only thing that I see is $\left\{\lvert f(1_A-1_{A_n})\rvert>\varepsilon/2\right\}\subset\left\{\lvert 1_A-1_{A_n}\rvert=1\right\}$.

Comment: I think this works. Give me some time... It seems harder tan i originally thought

Comment: Atm this only seems true when f is bounded... We need to somehow show the set f is big is small, if you know what i mean

Comment: Why does f have to be bounded? I do not see.

Comment: i assume your measure mu is not neccesarily finite?

Comment: Right, it does not have to be.

Comment: @mathfemi have we missed out something basic? If indicator of An converges to indicators of A, doesnt it mean An converges to A almost everywhere? Because where Indicator of An differ to indicator of A by epsilom, it means 1 of them is 0, the other must be 1?

Comment: So the comment the set at the end of the comment 'the only thing i see...' Has measure going to 0 as n goes to infinity

Comment: I do not understand your thought, because convergence in measure does not imply convergence almost everywhere to my knowledge.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12145/discussion-between-lost1-and-mathfemi)

Comment: 1_A(w) - 1_An(w) > \epsilon iff w is in one of them, gut not the other, if let epsilon be less than 1

Comment: So it is actually the same as the set w such that A (w) not equal to An(w) for epsilon less than 1

Comment: What I now see is the following: $\mu(\left\{\omega\in\Omega: \lvert 1_{A_n}(\omega)-1_A(\omega)\rvert > \varepsilon\right\}=\begin{cases}\mu(\emptyset)=0, &\text{ if }\varepsilon\geq 1\\\mu(\left\{\omega\in\Omega: \omega\in A_n\text{ or (exclusive) }\omega\in A\right\}, & \text{ if }0<\varepsilon<1\end{cases}$. But I do not see why it follows from this, that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\mu(\left\{\omega\in\Omega: \lvert 1_{A_n}(\omega)-1_A(\omega)\rvert=1\right\}=0$. Because this IS the second case?

Comment: @mathfemi yes because this is the 2nd case! Convince yourself!

Comment: Thank you very much for your great help!